# Why implementing more than two methods for method overloading is throwing error?

Tags: java

Why implementing more than two methods for method overloading is throwing error
The below code snippet implements method overloading of display methods
When I am executing two methods for overloading it is working fine.
However If I am executing three methods for overloading , it is throwing error

```
class TestVarArg {
    public static void display(int... ab)//method overloading
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int s : ab) {
            //int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            total = total + s;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum =" + total);
        System.out.println("The number of argument passed" + ab.length);
    }

    public static void display(int k)//method overloading
    {
        System.out.println("The standard method call display is" + k);
        System.out.println("======================================");
    }

    public static void display(int[]... aa)//method overloading
    {
        for (int[] a : aa) {
            System.out.println(a[0]);
        }
        System.out.println("====================");
    }
}

public class VargTest {
    public static void main(String... arg) {
        TestVarArg t = new TestVarArg();
        t.display();
        t.display(10);
        t.display(10, 20);
        t.display(10, 20, 30);
        int[] a = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int[] b = { 150, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
        t.display(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is throwing error ... ok, what error? most likely, it's this: int[]...aa that causes the problem.

Comment: Two methods (`display(int[]...aa)` and `display(int...aa)`) are applicable to the invocation `t.display();`. The compiler doesn't know which of the two to link.